# Recurring Payment integration in Autherize.net

Tags: payment-gateway, authorize.net

I integrated Autherize.net payment gateway using Server Integration Method,
How to do recurring payment option in Autherize.net SIM ? is it possible.

Answer (score 0):

No. It is not possible. SIM is for making payments only. If you wish to create a subscription programmatically you must use the [Automated Recurring Billing (ARB) API](http://developer.authorize.net/api/arb/).